# How do I calculate the group velocity of a waveguide?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, frequency, wavelength, dispersion

I understand that the group velocity is computed by $d\omega/dk$. Given the relationship between the wavelength of a waveguide and its frequency:
$$\lambda=\frac{c}{\sqrt{\nu^2-\nu^2_0}}$$

where $c$ is the speed of light.

How can I find an expression of the group velocity without knowing the dispersion formula? Is the dispersion relation something necessary to find the group velocity?

Comment: You have the dispersion formula. You want $\omega$ and it's given in terms of $\nu$ but that's just a factor of $2\pi$. You want $k$ and it's given in terms of $\lambda$ but that's just a reciprocal and another $2\pi$. So you just rewrite your $\nu,\lambda$ formula in terms of $\omega,k$. Then differentiate.

Comment: Thank you! But my teacher says I don't need the dispersion formula for it and I am confused... Is there a dispersion formula just for the waveguide? I tried to find it but couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just sum up what @RogerJBarlow saying in the comment.So you are given a relation
$$\lambda=\frac{c}{\sqrt{\nu^2-\nu_0^2}}$$

The first approch is to change this relation in terms of $\omega$ and $k$ with the help of relation $\omega= 2\pi \nu$ and $k=2\pi/\lambda$.
$$\frac{1}{k}=\frac{ c}{\sqrt{\omega^2-\omega_0^2}}$$
or $$k=\frac{\sqrt{\omega^2-\omega_0^2}}{c}$$
Now it's straight forward calculation to calculate $d\omega/dk$.

---

In case you don't want to do this, you can modify $d\omega/dk$ As the following
$$d\omega=2\pi d\nu$$ and $$dk=-2\pi\frac{1}{\lambda^2}d\lambda$$

so that $$\frac{d\omega}{dk}=-\lambda^2\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}$$

It's direct formula to compute group velocity. You this too can be used.

Comment: I really appreciate this! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Cheers! :) Hope this will help you.